# Find all matches (decimal) from string in SAP HANA with Regex

Tags: regex, hana

I need to extract all matches decimal numbers from string in SAP HANA

the text: **LOREN IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET 73,89 X 339,85 X 0,08 CBC70° 1000/2,5**

with

```
substr_regexpr('(\d(.*?)([\.\,]\d{1,3}))' in "Field" group 1
```

I extract only **73,89** from text.

with

```
\d(.*?)([\.\,]\d{1,3})+\d(.+?)([\,]\d{1,3})+\d(.*?)([\,]\d{1,3})
```

I extract the 3 values together: **73,89 X 339,85 X 0,08**

I need to extract this, but I am unable to do so.

```
substr_regexpr('(\d(.*?)([\.\,]\d{1,3}))' in "Field" group 1 ==> 73,89
substr_regexpr('(\d(.*?)([\.\,]\d{1,3}))' in "Field" group 2 ==> 339,85
substr_regexpr('(\d(.*?)([\.\,]\d{1,3}))' in "Field" group 3 ==> 0,08
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get 3 capturing groups as per shown samples, you may try following.

```
(?<=\s)(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s+X\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s+X\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)?)
```

[Demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/RW0oGu/1/)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
(?<=\s)          ##Checking look behind if spaces are present before next mentioned match.
(\d+(?:,\d+)?)   ##Creating 1st capturing group to match digits and ,digits as optional.
\s+X\s+          ##Matching spaces(1 or more occurrences) X spaces(1 or more occurrences).
(\d+(?:,\d+)?)   ##Creating 2nd capturing group to match digits and ,digits as optional.
\s+X\s+          ##Matching spaces(1 or more occurrences) X spaces(1 or more occurrences).
(\d+(?:,\d+)?)   ##Creating 3rd capturing group to match digits and ,digits as optional.
```

Comment: Thanks, this regex get that I need. 
One more thing, if one or more number is integer also? 
For example:
LOREN IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET 73,89 X 339 X 0,08 CBC70° 1000/2,5

Comment: @MarcosTaira, To use 3 capturing groups please use my EDIT solution once and let me know if All is Well with it.

Comment: @MarcosTaira, Sorry I didn't get it, could you please explain it more, what you want to catch here?

Comment: not all DB results are decimal numbers, some are integers

Comment: @MarcosTaira, sure, could you please test my edited solution now and let me know if that helps you? It will create 3 capturing groups with matching integers and float values. Please do let me know if my 1st solution works for you, I have removed my 2nd one now, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and thanks for the class with that explanations.